# JavaScript class and invocation context

Tags: javascript, class, object, closures

Can someone help me explain why the first example works, but the second doesn't.

#### Example 1:

```
// Define a class
function Foo(name) {
  var self = this;

  this.name = name;
  this.greeting = function() {
    console.log('Hello ' + self.name);
  }
}

var foo = new Foo('foo');
foo.greeting();

var greeting = foo.greeting;
greeting();
```

Output:

```
Hello foo
Hello foo
```

#### Example 2:

```
// Define a class
function Foo(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

// Greeting
Foo.prototype.greeting= function () {
  console.log('Hello ' + this.name);
}

var foo = new Foo('foo');
foo.greeting();

var greeting = foo.greeting;
greeting();
```

Output:

```
Hello foo
Hello undefined
```

My guess would be because the first example is using closure, so it retains the reference to the `name` local variable, but the second example is not, and since `greeting()` method is invoked without object context, it defaults to `undefined`.

Comment: Learn more about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 5):

There are four ways to invoke a function in JavaScript, each of which changes the value of `this` inside the function:

1. As a **global function** call: `greeting()`. The value of `this` is the global `window` object (in browsers).
2. As a **method** on some object: `foo.greeting()`. The value of `this` is the object instance on the left-hand side of the `.` operator (`foo`).
3. As a **constructor**: `new greeting()`. The value of `this` is a new object that is created and implicitly returned from the function. This is used to create new objects.
4. Using **`call` or `apply`**: `greeting.apply(someVal, someArgs)`. The value of `this` is the object passed as the first argument (`someVal`).

Any function can be executed in any of these four ways (although not all functions *should* be executed in some of them).

In the first case you're performing a method call:

```
var foo = new Foo('foo');
foo.greeting();
```

...so `this` is `foo` inside the function. In the second case you're performing a global function call:

```
var greeting = foo.greeting;
greeting();
```

...so `this` is `window` inside the function.

**Edit:** Note @jAndy's answer which points out the more salient issue in this case, which is that `greeting` closes over `self` in the first example (regardless of how it's called), but does not in the second (which then makes *how* the function is called relevant).

Comment: ... and then [`bind()` came along :).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @Matt - Very true, although `bind` doesn't *invoke* a function; it creates one.

Comment: it doesn't answer OPs question anyway.

Comment: @jAndy - Hah! So it doesn't. Good call.

Comment: @jAndy - Leaving my answer only because it's still relevant to the OP's second example. Also, added a note pointing to your answer.

Comment: Can someone please explain what is meant by 'greeting closes over self in the first example' in the comment at the end of the above post?

Comment: We say a function "closes over" the variables in its lexical scope to mean that it retains access to those variables inside its body, no matter how or when it's called. This means that the function `greeting` retains full access to `self` in the first example, because `self` was in its lexical scope at the time the function was created. No such situation exists in the second example.

Answer (score 5):

Many answers, all with useful and correct information, but none of them explains the behavior correctly.

In your first example, it only logs `Hello foo` both times, because you're creating a variable `self` which references the `this` object. That `self` variable is then closured in your `greeting function`. Hence, you can call that function however you want, it'll always access `self.name` and not `this.name` so its always the same.

You don't do that in your `prototype` example. There you directly access `this.name` and then it is indeed important of **how** the function is invoked (see @lwburk answer).

So again, even if you call the first example like

```
foo.greeting.call( window );
```

it would still access the closured `self` variable and log `Hello foo`.

Answer (score 2):

The resolution of `this` is delayed until execution time in JavaScript.

By setting `foo.greeting` to `greeting`, and then executing `greeting()` you're executing `greeting()` in the global context; in which `this` points to `window`<sup>unless you're running in strict mode</sup> and not your `Foo` instance. Because of this, inside `greeting()` it's looking for `window.name`; and returning `undefined.`

For a more detailed explanation, see [`this` on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: it doesn't answer OPs question anyway aswell.

Answer (score 0):

the second greeting() is executed on global scope, so accordingly `this` is the window object (the same scope in which the function is executed and `window.name` is then undefined). It works again if you pass a context via `apply()` or `call()`, eg.

```
var greeting = foo.greeting;
greeting.apply(foo);
```